# How to change Fluent UI icon color on mouse hover?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, fluent-ui, fluentui-react

i am using Fluent UI in my project.

I initializing my button with this simple code in javascript:

```
iconProps: { 
    iconName: 'NewFolder',
        styles: {
           root: { 
              color: 'orange' 
           }, 
    } 
},
```

and i can override default color to asked one.
[image]

My question is, how to set mouse hover color over button? [image]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/react/iiconprops?view=office-ui-fabric-react-latest#@fluentui-react-iiconprops-styles-member

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `IconButton`, `DefaultButton` and `PrimaryButton` you have property `root` for default button style, `rootHovered`, `rootChecked` etc. for different states.

```js
<IconButton
  iconProps={{ iconName: 'NewFolder' }}
  styles={{
    root: { color: 'blue' },
    rootHovered: { color: 'orange' },
  }}
/>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/savkelita/pen/NWyXWRN?editors=0010) working example

[Button styles](https://github.com/microsoft/fluentui/blob/master/packages/react/src/components/Button/IconButton/IconButton.styles.ts#L14) also might help.

Comment: Thanks, but i didn't be precise in this question. Can you check this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72402195/fluent-ui-style-not-working-in-passed-commands-with-buttons-to-commandbar

Comment: @michasaucer Yes i can but tell me what to focus on ?