# Fluent UI style not working in passed commands with buttons to CommandBar

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, fluent-ui, fluentui-react

i am using Fluent UI in my project. I dont know how to change `hoover` style in `CommandBar`.

I initializing my buttons with this simple code in javascript:

```
// inside `buttons` array
key: 'newfolder',
text: 'New Folder',
iconProps: { 
    iconName: 'NewFolder',
        styles: {
           root: { 
              color: 'orange' 
           }, 
           rootHovered: { 
              color: 'red' 
           }
    } 
},
onClick: ...
```

Then i am passing this buttons to `CommandBar`:

```
<CommandBar
    items={buttons}
        styles={{
            root: {
                paddingLeft: '5px'
            },
    }}
/>
```

and i can override default color to asked one.
[image]

My question is, how to set mouse hover color over button in `CommandBar` component? [image]

As you can see, it is still blue even if i passed `red` as rootHovered color. I cant pass `Hovered` prop to `CommandBar` because i get error:

```
(property) rootHovered: {}
Type '{ root: { paddingLeft: string; }; rootHovered: {}; }' is not assignable to type 'IStyleFunctionOrObject<ICommandBarStyleProps, ICommandBarStyles> | undefined'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'rootHovered' does not exist in type 'IStyleFunctionOrObject<ICommandBarStyleProps, ICommandBarStyles>'.ts(2322)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change it on hover by using buttonStyles prop like this:

```
text: 'New Folder',
buttonStyles: {
  iconHovered: {
    color: 'red'
  }
},
```

Find out more about this prop on: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/commandbar#implementation under section `ICommandBarItemProps interface`